# Logcat in Android Device Monitor only display certain messages

Tags: android, adb, logcat

I am not using Eclipse or Android Studio, I am just compiling my code myself and installing with adb.

If an uncaught exception or error occurs, it prints the the line number of the code that triggered it, but not the message.

If I call Log.d or Log.i, etc. , nothing happens. If I catch an exception and call e.printStackTrace() or System.err.println(), nothing happens.

What could be the issue?

Update: By the way, I am accessing logcat via the Android Device Monitor.
Update: It works fine using `adb logcat`. I just need it to work from Android Device Monitor now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you don't have any filter set.If you just use the following command you should be able to see all the logs.

```
adb logcat
```

if you want to see only logs with particular tag:

```
adb logcat -s "TAG"
```

Also make sure when you building the apk,you don't have any code that is disabling the logs-because its a release binary.

If you are viewing through IDE logcat view remove the filter.It must be there left hand side corner.If the filter level is **error**,you need to make it **verbose**.

Comment: I'm compiling with `ant debug` and my AndroidManifest.xml has `<application android:debuggable="true"...` so I think it should be fine.

Comment: Ok, yes, it did work fine when I typed `adb logcat` in the terminal, but that is a bit inconvenient. How can I get it to work from the logcat in `monitor`?

Comment: @geokavel in monitor remove the filter.It must be there left hand side corner.Right now I guess the filter level must be error,you need to make it verbose

Comment: As [you can see](http://pasteboard.co/uDzcXYT.png) filter level is "all messages(no filters)", and if I double click on that filter it says "Log level: Verbose".

Comment: @geokavel its weird..i would suggest use adb logcat from command line or use android studio..The logcat view in DDMS is not that reliable.

Comment: is there a way to put a filter on adb logcat, so it only shows messages from my application?

Answer (score 0):

I think your log level is too high for `Log.i` and `Log.d` (for example, if your log level is 'error' you only get error messages)

So set your log level to **verbose** to display all logs.

You can find the log level indicator in the top right of your Android tab in Android studio

Comment: hmm, I'm not using android studio though.

Comment: @geokavel call Log.v then, those should listen for pretty much all logs

Comment: @Bonatti I think it's the opposite. Verbose is the lowest priority.

Comment: @geokavel From the documentation: [The order in terms of verbosity, from least to most is ERROR, WARN, INFO, DEBUG, VERBOSE. Verbose should never be compiled into an application except during development. Debug logs are compiled in but stripped at runtime. Error, warning and info logs are always kept.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html)

Comment: @Bonatti If you call Log.v and log level is Debug, it won't get displayed, because verbose is lower than debug.